# Pyspark: compare one column with other columns and flag if similar

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm looking to create a column which flags if my column1 value is found in either column2, column3 or column4.

I can do it this way:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn("FLAG", f.when((f.col("column1") == f.col("column2")) |
                             (f.col("column1") == f.col("column3")) | 
                             (f.col("column1") == f.col("column4")), 'Y')\
                       .otherwise('N'))
```

This takes quite some time and I find it to be inefficient. I was wondering if there was a better way to write this using UDFs? And I'm trying to figure out how to reference which column there is a match from.

Any help helps! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spark built-in function [`isin`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = (spark
    .sparkContext
    .parallelize([
        ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
        ('A', 'B', 'C', 'A'),
        ('A', 'C', 'A', 'B'),
        ('A', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'),
    ])
    .toDF(['ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd'])
)

(df
  .withColumn('flag', F.col('ca').isin(
    F.col('cb'),
    F.col('cc'),
    F.col('cd'),
  ))
  .show()
)
# +---+---+---+---+-----+
# | ca| cb| cc| cd| flag|
# +---+---+---+---+-----+
# |  A|  A|  B|  C| true|
# |  A|  B|  C|  A| true|
# |  A|  C|  A|  B| true|
# |  A|  X|  Y|  Z|false|
# +---+---+---+---+-----+
```